# Save formated text from MVC 3 app to MSSQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

In my MVC 3 application i need to be able to edit text with formatting (ex bold text, linebreaks eks.), and send that edited text to a pdf document.
What i want is to put that formated text inside of a MSSQL DB, and be able to retrive it when needed.

Right now i am stuck at basics, when i am saving text to DB, db returns a long text string instead of formated text. Are there any other approaches of doing it?

For formatting i am using CKeditor library.

Maybe there are easier ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i am not wrong you can use html.raw helper to get the string in html . then store it in database. but using html.Raw, it will lead to security loops. user may do XSS attacks. 
you can use @Html.Raw(), with AntiForgeryTokens.

```
var someText = "<b>Hello World</b> blahblah"; 
@Html.Raw(someText);
```

[Html.Raw()](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/27/HtmlRawRazorViewEngine.aspx) ,     [Html.AntiForgeryToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492767.aspx)

Comment: is it smart to save it to Varchar in DB? or should i use something else?

Comment: it will return as HtmlString. so you need to assign HtmlString to your POCO objects